# How do I infinitely add children to this list tree?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to be able to infinitely add children/grandchildren/greatgrandchildren/etc. to this tree I am making. Currently I have it set up so it only goes 3 levels deep and I can't figure out a way to have it go as deep as the user wants.

HTML

```
<div class="tag-tree">
<ul id="addParent">
  <li class="root" class="add-child">
    <input /> <p class="add-child-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input />  <p class="add-gc-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p>      
    <ul> 
  <li><input /></li>
  <li><input /></li>
  <li><input /></li>
    </ul> 
  </li>
  <li><input /> <p class="add-gc-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p>   </li>
  <li>
    <input /> <p class="add-gc-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p>   
<ul>
  <li><input /></li>
  <li><input /></li>
</ul>  
  </li>
</ul>  
<div class="add-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Parent Tag</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".add-field").click(function() {
  $('#addParent').append('<li class="root" id="addChild"><input /> <p class="add-child-field" onclick="add_child();"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p></li>')
});

$(document).on('click', ".add-child-field", function() {
  $(this).parent().after('<li><input /><p class="add-gc-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p> </li>');
});



$(document).on('click', ".add-gc-field", function() {
  if ($(this).next('ul').length) {
    console.log(this)
    $(this).next('ul').append('<li><input /></li>');
  }
  else {
    console.log(this)
    $(this).after('<ul><li><input /></li></ul>');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y6ekn7d2/

Comment: you can just add a ".add-gc-field" inside click function like this [http://jsfiddle.net/y6ekn7d2/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/y6ekn7d2/5/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the liberty to simplify your code a little bit.

In order to maintain an arbitrary number of levels I treated all inputs same except the root ones. 
So that they all execute the same code to maintain their sublists. But the prevent the confusion, I added all input elements a "level" index.

```
<li>
  <input data-level="XXX" />
  <p class="add-field">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  </p>
</li>
```

Here is a modified version of your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/y6ekn7d2/2/

Answer (score 1):

With a slight change in your code, it is possible: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/y6ekn7d2/7/

```
$(document).on('click', ".add-gc-field", function () {
    if ($(this).next('ul').length) {
        console.log(this);
        $(this).next('ul').append('<li><input /><p class="add-gc-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p> </li>');
    } else {
        console.log(this)
        $(this).after('<ul><li><input /><p class="add-gc-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p> </li></ul>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

after along time I write this code :)

```js
$(document).on('click', ".add-child-field", function() {
  $(this).parent("li").find('ul').first().append('<li><input /><p class="add-child-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p><ul></ul></li>');
});
$(".add-field").click(function() {
  $('#addParent').append('<li><input /><p class="add-child-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p><ul></ul></li>')
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 50px;
  font-family: 'roboto';
  font-size: 13px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-family: Arial;
}
ul li {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
}
ul li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 0px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 10px;
}
ul li:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  bottom: -7px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 100%;
}
ul li.root {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px -20px;
}
ul li.root:before {
  display: none;
}
ul li.root:after {
  display: none;
}
ul li:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}

.add-field {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #404040;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.add-child-field, .add-child-field, .add-gc-field {
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="tag-tree">
  <ul id="addParent">
    <li class="root" class="add-child">
      <input />
      <p class="add-child-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p>
      <ul></ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input />
      <p class="add-child-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input />
          <p class="add-child-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input />
          <p class="add-child-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input />
          <p class="add-child-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input />
      <p class="add-child-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p>
      <ul></ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input />
      <p class="add-child-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input />
          <p class="add-child-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input />
          <p class="add-child-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></p>
          <ul></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="add-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Parent Tag</div>
</div>
```